# Remove duplicated numbers in text string from a column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have this example:

```
df <- structure(list(PdivR = c(0.93, 0.92, 0.97, 1.07, 1.08, 1.02, 
0.95, 0.92, 1.19, 0.99, 0.92, 1.02, 1.02, 0.88, 1.13, 0.97, 0.86, 
1.06, 0.98, 0.97, 1, 1.01, 0.96, 1.01, 1.02, 1.04, 0.98, 1.06, 
1.05, 0.97, 1.13, 0.97, 0.87, 1.06, 0.94, 1.03, 1.11, 1.11, 0.97, 
0.94, 1.05, 1, 0.94, 1.02, 1.04, 0.87, 1.17, 0.98, 0.95, 1.04, 
0.96, 0.99, 1.07, 1.04, 0.95, 1.01, 0.9, 1.09, 0.91, 1.02, 1.08, 
1.04, 1.1, 0.99, 0.84, 1.04, 1.05), Regression = c("TLC~8+8+10+10", 
"TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", 
"TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", 
"TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", 
"TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~8+8+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", 
"TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", 
"TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", 
"TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", 
"TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", 
"TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", 
"TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", 
"TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", 
"TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~9+9+10+10", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", 
"TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", 
"TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", 
"TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", 
"TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", 
"TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9", "TLC~7+7+8+8+9+9")), row.names = 1234:1300, class = "data.frame")
```

Which can be displayed in a dataframe

```
head(df)
     PdivR    Regression
1234  0.93 TLC~8+8+10+10
1235  0.92 TLC~8+8+10+10
1236  0.97 TLC~8+8+10+10
1237  1.07 TLC~8+8+10+10
1238  1.08 TLC~8+8+10+10
1239  1.02 TLC~8+8+10+10
```

If we focus our attention over the column `Regression`, we realize that numbers are repeated (`TLC~8+8+10+10`).

How can I remove these duplicated numbers in a fashion way in order to get the `Regression` column properly configured? In the previous example, the correct value will be `TLC~8+10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
df$Regression <- gsub("(\\d+\\+)\\1+", "\\1",
      gsub("(\\+\\d+)\\1+", "\\1", df$Regression))
```

---

Or may also use `strsplit`

```
df$Regression <- sapply(strsplit(df$Regression, "[[:punct:]]"), 
   function(x) deparse(reformulate(unique(x)[-1], response = x[1])))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. However, when I am having `TLC~8+8` for instance, the previous code seems to not been working

Comment: @antecessor is there any other pattern

Comment: basically all the combinations of 7,8,9,10 in my real dataset

Comment: I meant is this the only case that is failing

Comment: No, only when it is TLC~7+7, TLC~8+8, TLC~9+9 and TLC~10+10